# Convert strings A1.B1.C1+A1.B2+C1 to A1.B1+B2.C1

Tags: r

I would like to convert this v_in string into this v_out in R:

```
v_in <- 'A1.B1.C1+A1.B2.C1+A1.B2.C2'
v_out<-'A1.B1+B2.C1+C2'
```

Another example:

```
v_in <- 'A1.B1.C1+A2.B1.C1+A3.B1.C1'
v_out <- 'A1+A2+A3.B1.C1'
```

Here other examples:

```
in<-'FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A'
out<-'FRA+DEU.UNR.A'
```

```
in<-'FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A+ITA.GDP.A'
out<-'FRA+DEU+ITA.UNR+GDP.A'
```

```
in<-'FRA.UNR.A+FRA.GDP.Q'
out<-'FRA.UNR+GDP.A+Q'
```

```
in<-'A.B.C+A.D.E+A.D.F+G.H.I'
out<-'A+G.B+D+H.C+E+F+I'
```

The input pattern is:
S1+S2+S3  (where S1 is A.B.C, and same thing for S1 and S3)

The output should be:
X.Y.Z (where X is unique A codes (separate by+), Y: unique B codes (separate by+), and same thing for Z)

[image]

Comment: Give more examples in order for one to determine what you are trying to do. 2 examples are not enough

Comment: Does the data come to you like this, or have you created these `+`-collapsed strings and are hoping to reshape them into something more? If they look like this because of a previous processing step, it might be better to resolve the issue *there* and reshape the data correctly the first time.

Comment: Yes input data coming like this, I cannot change this input format, and I need to convert it to the output one

Comment: is the output of example 2 correct or should it be `A1.A2+A3.B1+C1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

In BASE R:

```
my_fun <- function(v){
  sapply(strsplit(v, '[+]'), 
     function(x) 
      do.call(paste, aggregate(.~sep, cbind(read.table(text=x, sep='.'), sep ='.'), 
                   function(y)paste(unique(y), collapse = '+'))))
}

my_fun(v_in)
[1] "A1.B1+B2.C1+C2"        "A1+A2+A3.B1.C1"        "FRA+DEU.UNR.A"        
[4] "FRA+DEU+ITA.UNR+GDP.A" "FRA.UNR+GDP.A+Q"
```

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(v_in, id = v_in) %>%
  separate_rows(id, sep='[+]') %>%
  separate(id, c('COUNTRY', 'VARIABLE', 'FREQUENCY')) %>%
  group_by(v_in) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~paste0(unique(.x), collapse = '+')))%>%
  unite(v_out,-v_in, sep='.')


v_in                          v_out                
  <chr>                         <chr>                
1 A1.B1.C1+A1.B2.C1+A1.B2.C2    A1.B1+B2.C1+C2       
2 A1.B1.C1+A2.B1.C1+A3.B1.C1    A1+A2+A3.B1.C1       
3 FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A           FRA+DEU.UNR.A        
4 FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A+ITA.GDP.A FRA+DEU+ITA.UNR+GDP.A
5 FRA.UNR.A+FRA.GDP.Q           FRA.UNR+GDP.A+Q
```

---

DATA:

```
v_in <- c("A1.B1.C1+A1.B2.C1+A1.B2.C2", "A1.B1.C1+A2.B1.C1+A3.B1.C1", 
"FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A", "FRA.UNR.A+DEU.UNR.A+ITA.GDP.A", "FRA.UNR.A+FRA.GDP.Q")
```